VSCode Oracle Language Server errors out
I recently installed the Java 23 JDK on my computer, and I went to VSCode in order to update the Java version it uses. However, I found it already broken.
When opening my Java project, I saw an error popup saying Error initializing Oracle Java SE Language Server not enabled.
In the associated terminal window, I found the following log:
Initiating server activation
Request to kill LSP server.
Cannot kill: current process is None
Launching Oracle Java SE Language Server with /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-23.jdk/Contents/Home and userdir /Users/rahulchoubey/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/bc14dfd84ed7c4f7a6d495fae3d0d875/Oracle.oracle-java
LSP server launching: 3851
LSP server user directory: /Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/bc14dfd84ed7c4f7a6d495fae3d0d875/Oracle.oracle-java
There are parameters but nobody wants to proces them: [Course, Files]
Cannot find org.netbeans.modules.java.lsp.server in the log!
Please refer to troubleshooting section for more info: https://github.com/oracle/javavscode/blob/main/README.md#troubleshooting
Request to kill LSP server.
Cannot kill: Requested kill on 3851, current process is None
Oracle Java SE Language Server not enabled

(The [username] is just a stand-in for my username.)
Based on the "parameters" message, the error might be that my folder name has a space in it, but it did not cause any problems before—the errors only started yesterday.
The relevant values in the settings.json file are as follows:
{
    …,
    "java.configuration.runtimes": [
        {
            "name": "JavaSE-23",
            "path": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-23.jdk/Contents/Home",
            "sources": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-23.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/src.zip",
            "default": true
        },
    ],
    "java.jdt.ls.java.home": "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-23.jdk/Contents/Home",
}

I don't believe the error is Netbeans-related, as I don't have that installed, and the extension worked just fine until now. The "troubleshooting" section only suggested clearing the cache, which does nothing.
One solution I've considered is renaming my project directory to have underscores; however, most of its subdirectories also have spaces in their names, so I'm not sure whether that solution is advisable.
(I searched here, but I only found this question. The only answer there was to install a JDK, and I'm not getting a "JDK not found!" popup along with the error.)

There are parameters but nobody wants to proces them: [Course, Files] is a pretty unexpected error message which is uncommon for "invaild argument",and also have a typo.Could you please confirm if it is from the original log?

The typo is part of the original log. The workspace folder is named [word] Course Files, which is why I suspected the spaces.

I had the same issue and fixed it by downgrading the Java extension from v23.0.0 to v22.1.2 (although, I have java 22, not 23)

Installing that version made the language server work again! I did have to reinstall the extension (I had deleted it in the meanwhile), but checking the logs showed that the language server ran properly.
